# Different URL when testing for development and production

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jenkins, tdd

I am starting to learn server-side development and want to do TDD. I am also deploying with Jenkins for Continuous Integration. When I run tests during development, I want to use "localhost" as the server name, but when the tests run with Jenkins, they should use the production server instead. How do I configure my JUnit tests to do this with as little pain as possible? I'm developing my backend with Spring, so using dependency injection is probably the right solution here. I just don't know the exact details nor enough about Spring and DI to even think of a decent google search.

Comment: are you running tests with maven?

Comment: @froderik I am building my app and running tests with Gradle.

Comment: aha - I don't know gradle well. In maven there are profiles that can be used for this. Maybe there are something similar in gradle? Profiles can be used to parameterize different environments.

Comment: @froderik http://www.coderanch.com/t/603665/tools/similar-Maven-profile-Gradle Apparently Gradle does have similar functionality. Thanks for the tip. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

You should use spring to wire-up your tests using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and add a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to the context you load for your tests. Now you can set a property with the server name in a variety of ways (SystemProperty, property file, CommandLine option -D). In the config, you can use `${serverName}` to get the value.

Comment: This will take some time for me to digest. At least I have some class names now that I can google and read more about. Thanks!